# Polar coordinates in the cartesian plane.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

${dy}/{dx} = {dy}/{d\theta}$ divided by $dx/d\theta$ where $x$ and $y$ are in the Cartesian plane and $\theta$ is in the polar plane and $x = r\cos( \theta), \ y = r \sin (\theta)$.

If $dy/dx = 0$ why does that have to mean that $dy/d\theta = 0$?  Why couldn't $d\theta/dx = 0$ instead?

Comment: You should perhaps take a look at this link here for using LaTeX. Symbols are enclosed in $$ signs, followed by the appropriate string for the symbol you want. You can draw the symbol in the box to see suggestions for the character you want.

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule you have

$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{d\theta}$

It follows that

$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$  $\Rightarrow$  $\frac{dy}{d\theta}=0$

Comment: But what if d(theta)/dx = o?  Then you would have 0 times infinity.

Comment: I'n not sure what you mean. $\frac{d\theta}{dx}=0$  implies  $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: d(theta)/dx = 0 implies that dx/d(theta) is infinity.  Therefore if dy/dx = 0 then dy/d(theta) = 0 times infinity.

Comment: Exactly why do you think that d(theta)/dx=0 implies that dx/d(theta) is infinity?

Comment: Generally speaking, du/dv = 1 divided by dv/du.  1 divided by 0 is infinity.

Comment: Infinity is not a number. And you can't look at dx and d(theta) separately since they are not numbers either.

Comment: So what if infinity is not a number.  And  it is a standard proof that du/dv = 1/ (dv/du)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14898/discussion-between-poolpt-and-mathperson).

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{\;\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\;}{\dfrac {\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\theta}}$$

$$y_x(x) = \dfrac{y_\theta(\theta)}{x_\theta(\theta)}=\dfrac{r \cos \theta}{-r \sin \theta}$$

So, if the LHS equals $0$, then the numerator on the RHS must equal $0$, or else the denominator must approach infinitude ($\infty$).

In this particular case the denominator is $- r\sin\theta$ which is never infinite.